# fscanf causes segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I'm writing a code that will count the number of processes who parent process is `init`. Called fork and had the child use an `exec` function and pass its output through a pipe back to the parent. All seemed fine on that end, but when I used `fdopen` on the parent's read-end of the pipe, followed by `fscanf` the program crashed, even though the `FILE` stream is not `NULL`. I placed checks on every function call.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

static void     fatalError(char *message);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    int     total, initCount = 0;
    int     pipeToParent[2];
    pid_t   pid;
    FILE    *file;



    if (pipe(pipeToParent) < 0)
        fatalError("pipe() error");

    if ((pid = fork()) < 0)
        fatalError("fork() error");
    else if (pid == 0) {

        if (close(pipeToParent[0]) < 0)
            fatalError("close() error");

        if (dup2(pipeToParent[1], STDOUT_FILENO) < 0)
            fatalError("dup2() error");

        execlp("ps", "ps", "ahxo", "ppid", NULL);
        fatalError("exec() error");

    }


    if (close(pipeToParent[1]) < 0)
        fatalError("close() error");

    wait(NULL);

    if ((file = fdopen(pipeToParent[0], "r")) == NULL)
        fatalError("fdopen() error");


    for (total = 0; fscanf(file, "%d", &pid) != EOF; total++)
        if (pid == 1)
            initCount++;

    if (fclose(file) < 0)
        fatalError("fclose() error");

    printf("%.2f%%\n", (float) initCount * 100 / total);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);


}


static void     fatalError(char *message) {
    perror(message);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Running GDB gave this:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__isoc99_fscanf (stream=0x55757260, format=0x555555554c44 "%d") at isoc99_fscanf.c:30
30  isoc99_fscanf.c: No such file or directory.
```

And the Makefile warnings:

```
gcc -std=c11 -g -Wall -pedantic    init.c   -o init
init.c: In function ‘main’:
init.c:55:14: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘fdopen’; did you mean ‘fopen’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  if ((file = fdopen(pipeToParent[0], "r")) == NULL)
              ^~~~~~
              fopen
init.c:55:12: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
  if ((file = fdopen(pipeToParent[0], "r")) == NULL)
            ^
```

Comment: [isoc99_fscanf.c](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/stdio-common/isoc99_fscanf.c.html) has some macro on line 30, but it's unknown if it's that version. And it doesn't seem like it would fail. Why do you have debug information included with glibc? What OS are you running? What glibc version do you have? Btw. `fscanf(file, "%d", &pid)` returns 1 on success, you should probably ignore cases when it returns 0.

Comment: I did get a warning asking me if I meant `fopen` instead of `fdopen`, not sure if that helps, but I certainly didn't mean the former

Comment: Did you get a warning that the function is implicit declared? `warning: implicit declaration of function ...`

Comment: OT:  If an `exec*()` function fails after a `fork()`, you almost certainly don't want to call `exit()` afterwards - that will flush any buffered data copied from the parent's address space to the child's address space into the parent's files.  It will also call all exit handlers registered by the parent process.  `_exit()` exists for a reason.

Comment: OT: regarding: `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`  When the parameters to `main()` are not going to be used, then use the signature: `int main( void )`

Comment: strongly suggest reading the MAN page for `fdopen()`  especially the part about  "Feature Test Macro Requirements for glibc"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C  if no previous declaration of function exist it is assumed the function returns an `int`. If the compiler assumes the function returns an `int` while it returns `FILE *` and if `sizeof(FILE*) < sizeof(int)` the return value is truncated and is invalid. Thus you get internal glibc errors as the pointer passed to `fscanf` is truncated and invalid.

From [man fdopen](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fdopen) you can read:

```
fdopen(): _POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 1 || _XOPEN_SOURCE || _POSIX_SOURCE
```

These are the macros that you need to define to have `fdopen()` declaration in your program. You need to define them *before* any inclusion. I usually just define `_GNU_SOURCE` which defines `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` etc. in `features.h`.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

.. rest of the program ...
```

For more information see [future test macros](https://linux.die.net/man/7/feature_test_macros).

When using `gcc` you can also do `gcc -std=gnu11` or other `-std=gnu*`. `-std=c11` is the same as `-std=gnu11` except the macro `_GNU_SOURCE` is predefined when compiling.

Answer (score 2):

Per the [Linux man page for `fdopen()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fdopen.3.html), Linux/glibc requires definition of the `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` macro:

> Feature Test Macro Requirements for glibc (see
>   [feature_test_macros(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html)):
>
> ```
>    fdopen(): _POSIX_C_SOURCE
> ```

Otherwise, you get an implicit declaration, which as already noted means the function is assumed to return `int`.  And the pointer that `fdopen()` actually returns likely doesn't fit into that `int`, so it's truncated.